# Trigger after insert doesn't work although all data is deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

My table is empty and I'm trying to insert a record with the condition that the bit type column is not true, because the true condition can only be once for each country. Here is my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trg_PreventDefaultDevise] 
ON [dbo].[RELDEVISEPAYS]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Pays varchar(2);
    DECLARE @Compte int = 0;

    --select @Default = Rel_Default from Inserted;

    SELECT @Pays = REL_PAYS FROM inserted
    PRINT @Pays

    SET @Compte = (SELECT COUNT(rel_pays) FROM inserted 
                   WHERE Rel_Pays = @Pays AND Rel_Defaut = 0)
    PRINT @compte;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RELDEVISEPAYS 
        WHERE REL_DEFAUT = 1 AND REL_PAYS = @Pays) >= 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR (N'Ce pays dispose déjà d''une devise par défaut', 16, 1)
        ROLLBACK
        RETURN
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `select @Pays = REL_PAYS from inserted` is making the classic SQL Server trigger mistake - which is assuming there will only be a single row in the `Inserted` psuedo-table - when in fact there could be many.

You don't really need the `Inserted` table to carry out your test. Instead just check the real table for any duplicates and if there are rollback.

What I think you want is:

```
alter trigger [dbo].[Trg_PreventDefaultDevise] on [dbo].[RELDEVISEPAYS]
after insert, update
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if exists (select 1 from dbo.RELDEVISEPAYS where REL_DEFAUT = 1 group by REL_PAYS having count(*) > 1)
    begin
        raiserror (N'Ce pays dispose déjà d''une devise par défaut',16,1);
        rollback;
    end;
end
```

Comment: ah it's true, i just tested and it works from god’s fire, thank you very much

Comment: Hi Dale, thank you for your help, but I would like to understand why my request was not working. can you explain to me ?

Comment: As I say in the first line of my answer, you are setting `@Pays` to the 1 random value in `Inserted`, and then only testing for that 1 value. When in fact `Inserted` may have multiple rows, you will be ignored the rest of them.

Comment: SQL Server triggers always need to be written in a set based way to handle the fact that `Inserted` has multiple rows. Or if you really really have to, you can iterate over `Inserted` and process it one row at at time, but that should be avoided if at all possible.